# How to get unread message in my SMS app android

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I have created an SMS app for all versions. I am using the cursor adapter for showing the Message and number. Things are working fine except that I am not able to differentiate the new messages?

How to fix this SMS unread part? I would like to BOLD them when I receive it. But I don't know how what is received.

What I am doing now:

In my SMS receiver I store the new numbers to local DB and then compare them with the SMS content provider. This works just fine, but then takes a lot of time to load the messages.

How to fix this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with a few trial and errors..

Got the Read value for particular number and corresponding message( if "0" then bold them according).

To mark read I did the following:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
String selection = "address = ? AND body = ? AND read = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = {from, body, "0"};

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("read", true);

context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, selection, selectionArgs);
```

Hope it helps for people who are looking for solution...